# bash aliases not configured when starting new terminal session

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a Z shell terminal, and I want to configure some aliases to use.

I have made a `.bash_profiles` file to configure some commands.

This works great after I run this command `$ source ~/.bash_profiles`

but I have to do it every time i start up a new terminal session.

Is there a way to persist this, so I only have to configure this once??

Comment: zsh != bash. Do you have a .zshrc? Input the command into this file and start a new zsh see if this works.

Comment: On top of the comments and answers; If the aliases should be bash compatible, the file should be named .bash_profile, and not .bash_profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Z shell looks for `~/.zshrc` by default, so you can add such a line to `~/.zshrc`:

```
source ~/.bash_profiles
```

Create the file if it doesn't exist already, or *append* to its end so your `source` becomes effective after all original content has been processed.